# Android splash screen for high resolution devices

Tags: android

I need to design a splash screen for my app, but Iam facing issues for high end devices like Nexus 6p.

Ihave samsung s5 with 1080X1920px size which is xxhdpi
and nexus 6p with1440 x 2392px size which is also a xxhdpi

when ever i place my splashscreen.png(with 1080X1920 size ) in drawable-xxhdpi
6p is giving slight distortion as the resolution is more in it, it works fine in samsung s5.

since both are xxhdpi screen what is the correct image size i need to place.

Comment: Using a 1080x1920 or lager image defies the point of a splashscreen, because showing the splashscreen even takes time with such an image.

Comment: My point is i can use only one image in drawable-xxhdpi so it should fit both the device but my 6p is showing little bit distortion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you display the image with scale type CENTER_CROP there should be no distortion. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the composition of your splash screen, you may be able to use a 9patch image, which is basically an image with resizable sections configured in such a way that Android can understand them.

There is an overview of what they are at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch, and information on how to create one at https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html